# Meanings of Issue Status in Issue Tracker System

Tags: issue-tracking

There are some conventional issue status in almost issue tracker systems:

`New`, `In Progress`, `Resolved`, `Feedback`, `Closed` and `Rejected`.

- `New`: A new issue to be resolved.
- `In progress`: Someone is working on this issue.
- `Resolved`: After resolving the issue, set the status to `Resolved`, close the issue after the  verification (ex. Project manager).
- `Feedback`: ???
- `Closed`: The final status to every issues.
- `Rejected`: ???

I want to know in what situation should I change the status of an issue into `Feedback` or `Rejected`?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to locate content of much value describing "Feedback." However, I could imagine an issue going into "Feedback" status either at some point before it is resolved, or once it is resolved. Pre-resolution, it could possibly indicate the person assigned to work on the issue is seeking clarification of the issue's description, or possibly the person who reported the issue has some afterthought whether implementation could cause some other aspect of the project to break and is looking for input to support or refute the concern. Post-resolution, "Feedback" may be to request a little bit of extra tuning before closing the issue, or perhaps to suggest the implementation is totally flawed! Generally, I would say think of the "Feedback" status as indicating some form of, well, feedback is going on in either direction between the reporter and the assignee.

In terms of "Rejected," I suppose situations where one would use it include closing a bug that turned out to not actually be a bug. Think of it as a way of closing an issue unresolved.

Answer (score -1):

`Resolved`: is used when programmer fix issue and issue is going to CodeReview or testing.

`Rejected`: is used, when tester or code review fails and it's returned to programmer for fix problems.

`Invalid`: when bug is not valid (missing relevant parts, is not replicable, ...)

`Feedback`: can be reopened issue (IMHO, but not sure)